# how to display live feed data from an asp .net website to my site?

Tags: .net, asp-classic, feed

I would like to know how I can get a live data to be displayed in my website using asp .net without knowing their database nor connected to their db? The site has live feed of stock price, and I would like to get the prices and be displayed to my mini site, updates too when price changes. No DB involve in here. Any idea how? thanks.

Comment: Why classic ASP tag? How is it relevant?

Answer (score 0):

You may use a timer to re-download their data. The only quick and dirty example (using AJAX) that comes to my mind is in the examples section of the jqgrid plugin.

Comment: I am not sure if that is what I am looking for. I have searched about screen scraping but the UI is not possible for me to screen scrape since it is in rich ui format and not html. or is it? any idea? thanks

Comment: Do you need to get a RSS feed or to display a part of their page? In the second case (dirty and raw!) you may use an iframe and jquery to extract just a sub-section (but you have to identify it somehow, id?)